# Does Muirhead's Also Work on Cyclic Inequalities?

Tags: inequality, muirhead-inequality

So I am trying to learn how to solve inequalities, and came across the following in one of the problems I was trying to solve:

$\frac{b^3}{a}$+$\frac{c^3}{b}$+$\frac{d^3}{c}$+$\frac{a^3}{d}\geq ab+bc+cd+da$

After multiplying both sides by $abcd$, I get

$b^4cd+c^4da+d^4ab+a^4bc\geq a^2b^2cd+b^2c^2da+c^2d^2ab+d^2a^2bc$

I know (4,1,1,0) majorizes (2,2,1,1), so I want to apply Muirhead's, but these are cyclic sums, not symmetric sums... can I still apply Muirhead's or do I have to do it a different way?

Comment: No, sadly, Muirhead is wrong in general for cyclic sums.

Comment: I think one might try systematically solving this with weighted AM-GM: For any $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta\ge0$, we have $$\alpha a^4 b c+\beta b^4 c d+\gamma c^4 d a+\delta d^4 a b\ge(\alpha+\beta+\gamma+\delta)\cdot\sqrt[\alpha+\beta+\gamma+\delta]{a^{4\alpha+\gamma+\delta}b^{4\beta+\delta+\alpha}c^{4\gamma+\alpha+\beta}d^{4\delta+\beta+\gamma}}.$$ Now see if you can properly choose $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta$ to obtain each one of the terms on the right-hand side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Muirhead doesn't work, because it is wrong in general for cyclical sums. However, my suggested approach in the comments does work:

For any $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta\ge0$ with $\alpha+\beta+\gamma+\delta>0$,

$$\alpha a^4 b c+\beta b^4 c d+\gamma c^4 d a+\delta d^4 a b\ge(\alpha+\beta+\gamma+\delta)\cdot\sqrt[\alpha+\beta+\gamma+\delta]{a^{4\alpha+\gamma+\delta}b^{4\beta+\delta+\alpha}c^{4\gamma+\alpha+\beta}d^{4\delta+\beta+\gamma}}$$

by weighted AM-GM.

Choose $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta)=(9,7,1,3)$ (I got this by solving a linear equation system, feel free to ask me to elaborate; I am a bit in a rush at the moment) to get

$$9a^4 bc+7 b^4 c d+c^4da+3d^4 a b\geq20 a^2b^2cd.$$

Permuting $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta)$ cyclically around $(9,7,1,3)$ gives you analogous inequalities. Adding them up yields $$20 a^4bc+20 b^4cd+20 c^4da+20 d^4ab\geq 20a^2b^2cd+20b^2c^2da+20c^2d^2ab+20d^2a^2bc,$$ which is exactly what you want.

Comment: This is great! Just wondering though-could you provide a counterexample of why Muirhead doesn't work with cyclical sums?

Comment: @TheEpicCarrot7 Actually this is a highly interesting follow-up question since constructing a counter-example is really hard. I refer to the very interesting discussion here, it seems that this discussion includes some pretty general results for three variables on when the Muirhead-type inequality for cyclic sums holds and when it doesn't: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h103761

Comment: In particular, the inequality-legend Vasc says something really interesting about it: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h103761p681279

Comment: As a meta-comment: The remark posted by Spanferkel in that 2006-AOPS-thread about the publication by Vasc in 1987 saying „as much as 19 years ago...“ is pretty funny, seeing that the thread itself is close to 19 years old now . To anyone that finds this comment in 19 years: Please let me know!!